# The chain of identity would have been broken

Tags: word-usage

> Epicurus’ view was that we consist of atoms (though what he meant by
>   this term was a bit different from what modern scientists mean by it).
>   Once these atoms come apart at death we no longer exist as individuals
>   capable of consciousness. Even if someone could carefully put all the
>   bits back together again later, and breathe life back into this
>   reconstructed body, it wouldn’t be anything to do with me. The new
>   living body wouldn’t be me, despite looking like me. I wouldn’t feel
>   its pains, because once the body ceases to function nothing can bring
>   it back to life. **The chain of identity would have been broken**.

(A little history of philosophy - Nigel Warburton)

Why did the author use "**would have**" in "**The chain of identity would have been broken**"? I don't understand the usage in this case. Could you explain this for me?

Answer (score 1):

We use *would + have + past participle* to talk about a **hypothetical situation in the past**:

- I would have liked to be an actor. (in the past; I don't like the idea anymore)
- I wouldn't have got wet. (I didn't have an umbrella, so I got wet; if I had had an umbrella, I wouldn't have got wet).
- The chain would have been broken. (In fact, it wasn't broken; I am just making a supposition).

You may want to read up on third conditionals, because "would + have + past participle" is the main clause of this type of conditionals. [This article](https://enguroo.com/2018/06/08/conditionals/) may help.